# Booting ASUS P8-H61-MLX without keyboard

Tags: windows-10, boot, keyboard, bios

So, the next phase of setting up my old PC as a network server - I need it to boot without a keyboard connected. Right now it sounds an error beep during checkup and refuses to boot. I couldn't find the right setting for it in the BIOS...

The MB is an ASUS P8-H61-MLX, and the PC is running Windows 10.

How is it done? I really don't want to plug in KVM adapters and such...

**EDIT:** I've updated the BIOS but still can't find it there. I hope that doesn't mean I'm doomed...

Comment: Have your tried disabling "Wait for F1 If Error"?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it's disabled to begin with.

Comment: What's the beep code it gives?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It's two short beeps - the regular bios load beep followed with a beep best described as an error beep - kinda like the ones you see on TV trivia shows when you give the wrong answer.

Comment: See this...https://ask.slashdot.org/story/04/07/13/0416239/dongles-to-fake-presence-of-a-keyboard... https://ask.slashdot.org/story/04/07/13/0416239/dongles-to-fake-presence-of-a-keyboard

Comment: @moab Except the option to rip apart an old keyboard's controller and plugging it it, slashdot provided no help to me.